# When does PDOStatement:execute() return false and when does it throw PDOException?

Tags: php, pdo

This has been bugging me for a while. [Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php) states that PDOStatement::execute() returns FALSE "on failure".

In reality, in all practical instances I have ever observed, a failure in PDOStatement::execute() always throws PDOException. Despite that, aside of the exception handling, I have always been adding "belts and braces" code to test for returned FALSE. That makes code less clean, particularly as it is hard to unit test that part of the code.

Are there any particular circumstances when execute() would not throw PDOException, but would return FALSE instead or is testing for FALSE obsolete these days?

Comment: _"Are there any particular circumstances when execute() would not throw PDOException"_? Yes! `$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_SILENT)`

Comment: Thanks! Just what I was looking for. [Error handling documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php) answers that. This can be set as a default option in the PDO object constructor, which is what I have been doing, it seems.

Comment: Aside from the actual matter at hand, you can always write a wrapper function that would contain all the "belts and braces" you wish to add and then call this wrapper instead, making your code clean and innnocent